# Thunar not authorized to acces mounted volumes

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, fluxbox

I'm running a minimal ubuntu with fluxbox as wm and no display manager. I start fluxbox with startx and mainly use the fluxbox startup script for my application autostart which includes "thunar --daemon"

I'm using thunar with thunar-volman as my file manager but I'm unable to access mounted volumes with thunar. They appear on the side bar but when I click the volume it prompts the following message:

Failed to mount "volume": 
Not authorized to perform the operation

Answer (score 0):

Check if polkit-gnome is installed, if it isn't install it.

In the fluxbox startup script add the folowing lines:

`# Polkit agent:
/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &`

Also make sure all volumes you want mounted are in /etc/fstab.

After reboot you should be authorized to access mounted volumes